# Bevel highlight with no additional markup

Tags: html, css

[image: bevel]

Do you see the thin bevel highlight on top? How do you do this in CSS with only one HTML tag? I'm guessing it has something to do with `outline`. This is what I have so far without the bevel:

```
<a class="callToAction">Click here</a>

.callToAction {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 -moz-border-radius: 0.4em;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #ccc,
  #999
 );
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to highlight it? On hover? Active? Or permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that you can specify a shadow to be an inset by inspecting the source of http://html5doctor.com/you-can-still-use-div/:

```
.inset {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 
             0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 
             0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a bevel you must use a combo of the CSS3 radius and shadow attributes. To get the highlight when hovering over a button you must use the pseudo-selector :hover.

The Button Code from http://www.whitedogdesigngroup.com/blog/entry/a_better_button_with_css3/

```
callToAction {
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-shadow: 0 -2px #791c13;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd, 0 -1px 1px #555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd, 0 -1px 1px #555;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd, 0 -1px 1px #555;
}

callToAction:hover {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  height: 29px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  color: #eee !important;

  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #eee, 0 -2px 1px #555;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #eee, 0 -2px 1px #555;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #eee, 0 -2px 1px #555;
}
```

If you need further explanation...

Explanation of CSS3 borders: http://doctype.tv/borders

Explanation of CSS3 shadows: http://doctype.tv/css3

Comment: If I use the dual box shadows, then IE won't have a border at all.